# SharePoint workflow list item permission

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, permissions, designer-workflow

I'm working on a 2010 workflow that runs when an item is created and should grant a user read/edit access to that specific list item. The list admins will have full control but the users will have read/edit access only to their list item and shouldn't be able to see/edit other user's items. How can I achieve this with sharepoint designer workflow?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your not assigning permissions using groups how are you doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "Replace item level permission" action for this. With this you can modify listitem permissions.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Roji.Joy/how-to-set-item-level-permission-using-sharepoint-designer-2/

http://spcycle.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html

There is other free activities available to assign permissions. You can use this also as per your requirement.

https://spdactivities.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grant%20Permission%20on%20Item

Comment: I have done very similar to above using "Add item level permission" and it works fine but only if the user is in one of the permission groups. I can't seem to be able to give them access just to that list item so when they visit the list they'll just see their item.

Answer (score 1):

in SharePoint Workflow 2010, there is action called "Replace", it will stop inheriting all parent permission to current item ,   and assign new permission to current list item

in below  i have replace Current item level permission , group XYZ with Contribute permission ,

Here is **workflow action**:-

"Replace **Contribute** of item in Current Item"

u can do same like for your solution